# Google Chrome UI

Tags: google-chrome

Can you help me guys restore the default Google Chrome User Interface? My chrome suddenly restarted and when it opened again this new UI popuped. I don't know if this is a new version of Chrome or Not. Let me know guys thanks! Added screenshot also

[image: Chrome UI]

Comment: Try googling, maybe something will come out like http://lifehacker.com/how-to-ditch-chromes-new-material-design-and-get-the-ol-1784822156 Anyway this question is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Open a new tab and goto chrome://flags/#top-chrome-md (may have to type it in the address bar) and change it's value to `Non-material`

If the # link doesn't work, search for `Material Design in the browser's top chrome`

Comment: I'm downvoting this because questions not related to programming should be closed and/or moved to other relevant sites like superuser.com, not being answered and thus clutter the site. Moreover, in this case an answer can be googled in a few seconds.